# How to set the 'source address' ProxySQL uses to connect to MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb, docker, proxysql

I'm deploying ProxySQL on Docker. When I try connecting to my database via ProxySQL, MariaDB rejected my login attempt as follows:

```
Access denied for user 'usarr'@'172.18.0.1'
```

(172.18.0.1 is the container's "internal" IP address.)

The Docker host itself has LAN address of 192.168.9.22. And the user configured in MariaDB is `'usarr'@'192.168.9.%'`

How do I configure ProxySQL to connect as `usarr@192.168.9.22`?

I've tried reading the (very confusing) documentation for ProxySQL and couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

The ProxySQL connection uses just the username `usaddr`.

The MariaDB grant of the hostname grants access to the IP, so `'usarr'@'192.168.9.%'` gives access to the connections from `192.168.9.0/24`.

What you want however is the connections to `172.18.0.1`, so create the user as `'usaddr'@'172.18.0.%'` of an applicable subnet.

See: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-user/#user-name-component

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this because I didn't create the user in ProxySQL *as well as* MariaDB. If you look at the (yes, often confusing) [docs](https://proxysql.com/documentation/ProxySQL-Configuration/) (**MySQL Users** heading) you'll see that you first need to create the user on your primary DB server and then within ProxySQL itself.

Here's an abbreviated example. First, create the user on your primary DB server (change the permissions and password as necessary):

```sql
MariaDB [(none)]> grant all on *.* to 'stnduser'@'%' identified by 'stnduser';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)
```

Then create the same user in ProxySQL:

```
ProxySQL Admin> INSERT INTO mysql_users(username,password,default_hostgroup) VALUES ('stnduser','stnduser',1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

ProxySQL Admin> SELECT * FROM mysql_users;                                                                                                                      
+----------+----------+--------+---------+-------------------+----------------+---------------+------------------------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------------+
| username | password | active | use_ssl | default_hostgroup | default_schema | schema_locked | transaction_persistent | fast_forward | backend | frontend | max_connections |
+----------+----------+--------+---------+-------------------+----------------+---------------+------------------------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------------+
| stnduser | stnduser | 1      | 0       | 1                 | NULL           | 0             | 0                      | 0            | 1       | 1        | 10000           |
+----------+----------+--------+---------+-------------------+----------------+---------------+------------------------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ProxySQL Admin> LOAD MYSQL USERS TO RUNTIME;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

ProxySQL Admin> SAVE MYSQL USERS TO DISK;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Then test the connection:

```
$ mysql -u stnduser -pstnduser -h 127.0.0.1 -P16033 -e"SELECT @@port"
+--------+
| @@port |
+--------+
|   3306 |
+--------+
```

If you don't add the ProxySQL user, this is what you'll see:

```
$ mysql -u stnduser -pstnduser -h 127.0.0.1 -P16033 -e"SELECT @@port"
ERROR 1045 (28000): ProxySQL Error: Access denied for user 'stnduser'@'172.29.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

The IP address will be whatever private IP range your Docker installation is using.